# Scala implicit for arbitrarily deep Functor composition

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to provide extension methods to an existing class `Elem` in Scala. However, I also want the operations to be available to any `M[Elem]`, as long as a Scalaz `Functor` for `M` is in scope. The behavior is always to apply the operation to the functor by using `map`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

class Elem

implicit class Ops[F[_]: Functor, A <% Elem](self: F[A]) {
  def foo = self.map(_ => "bar")
}

val elem = new Elem

// TODO (nice to have): can we avoid this "explicit implicit" conversion?
implicit def idOps[A <% Elem](self: A) = new Ops[Id, A](self)

elem.foo                        // bar
Option(elem).foo                // Some(bar)
List(elem).foo                  // List(bar)
```

I want to go further and make my extension methods available to arbitrarily deep functors, such as `List[Option[Elem]]` and `Option[Option[Option[Elem]]]`. I was able to write an implicit providing `Ops` for the composition of two functors, but I was not able to generalize it to arbitrary nesting depths:

```
// TODO: can we improve this to provide arbitrarily deep functor composition?
implicit def compositeOps[F[_]: Functor, G[_]: Functor, A <% Elem](self: F[G[A]]) = {
  implicit val FG = implicitly[Functor[F]].compose[G]
  new Ops[({ type FG[X] = F[G[X]] })#FG, A](self)
}

List(Option(elem)).foo          // List(Some(bar))
Option(List(Option(elem))).foo  // doesn't compile
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an implicit helper available recursively:

```
sealed trait Helper[FA] {
  type A
  type F[_]
  def w(fa: FA): F[A]
  val f: Functor[F]
}
trait Helper1 {
  implicit def nil[A] = new Helper[A] {
    type A = A
    type F[X] = X
    def w(a: A) = a
    val f = implicitly[Functor[Id]]
  }
}
object Helper extends Helper1 {
  implicit def cons[FA1, RA](implicit u: Unapply[Functor, FA1]{type A = RA},
    rest: Helper[RA]) = new Helper[FA1] {
    type A = rest.A
    type F[X] = u.M[rest.F[X]]
    def w(fa: FA1) = u.TC.map(u.apply(fa))(rest.w)
    val f = rest.f.compose(u.TC) //or the other way around, I can never remember
  }
}
implicit def compositeOps[FA, A1](self: FA)(
  implicit helper: Helper[FA]{type A = A1}, conv: A1 => Elem) = {
    implicit val FG = helper.f
    new Ops[helper.F, helper.A](helper.w(self))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found two issues with your solution: 1) I really need an implicit conversion from `A` to a fixed `Elem` type as in the example. Is there any way to work with that and your `Helper` other than including the `A => Elem` implicit as a `val` in the body of `Helper`? 2) The compiler can't find `Helper` instances for subclasses of the functors themselves, e.g. I cannot apply `Ops` to a `Some`. Is there any way to lift that restriction? I am aware that this already happens with Scalaz type classes, but in my case it is particularly important to be able to do that.

Comment: 1) `<%` is just sugar for an implicit `A => Elem`; I've added that to the compositeOps in the example.
2) It's not really possible; this is an ongoing debate in scalaz, but if we declared things to be co/contravariant then this would lead to cases where `Any` was inferred instead of what should be a type error. It is possible to declare a `Functor[Some]` but that will probably get you into trouble. The recommended approach is to use "smart constructors" like scalaz's `some` that return the appropriate types (in this case `Option[A]` rather than `Some[A]`).

Comment: I knew about `<%`, but I didn't know how to obtain the type of `A1` and didn't think of doing `{type A = A1}`. And I guess I'll work around the subclasses issue then. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can create a trait to represent what you want

```
trait DeepFunctor[X, A] {
  type Result[_]
  def map[B](x: X)(f: A => B): Result[B]
}
```

Note that it allows `X` to be mapped into a `Result[B]`. `X` could be anything at this point.

The simplest version is where we say that `X` equals `A`. The result should then be `Id[B]`. It's put in a trait to make sure it has low priority.

```
trait LowerPriorityDeepFunctor {
  implicit def identity[A] =
    new DeepFunctor[A, A] {
      type Result[x] = Id[x]
      def map[B](x: A)(f: A => B) = f(x)
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to ask for the `Functor` of `Id`.

The more complex version is where `X` is some container for which a `Functor` is defined.

```
object DeepFunctor extends LowerPriorityDeepFunctor {
  implicit def deep[F[_], X, A](
    implicit F: Functor[F], inner: DeepFunctor[X, A]) =
    new DeepFunctor[F[X], A] {
      type Result[x] = F[inner.Result[x]]
      def map[B](x: F[X])(f: A => B) = F.map(x)(inner.map(_)(f))
    }
}
```

The result of the `deep` method is a `DeepFunctor` for `F[X]`. Since we know nothing about `X` we request a `DeepFunctor` for `X`. This will recursively search for `DeepFunctor` instances until it reaches `identity`.

Your `Ops` class now becomes relatively simple

```
implicit class Ops[X](self: X) {
  def foo[A](implicit F: DeepFunctor[X, A]) = F.map(self)(_ => "bar")
}
```

Note that the `_` is now of type `A`. If you want to restrict to a certain type you can define `A` as `A <: SomeType`. If you want to be able to support an implicit conversion you can use an extra implicit argument `ev: A => SomeType`. If you want to make `A` a specific type, you can remove the `A` and put `SomeType` in the `DeepFunctor` directly.

Comment: This looks like a clean and relatively easy to understand solution! The only thing that bothers me a little is that I have to request an implicit `DeepFunctor` in each method and not in the class itself, as I have much more than one operation like `foo` and I would have to change all their signatures. I tried to move `A` and `F` to the class signature but I had no luck, as the result for each method is type-dependent on the `DeepFunctor` and client code would not resolve its type to the original functor composition. Do you see any way I can avoid this? If not that's OK :)

Comment: @RuiGonçalves Yeah, it seems the problem is caused by `type Result[x] = F[inner.Result[x]]`. I think this is a compiler bug, but I don't know for sure. If the implicit is moved to the class itself, the `Result[x]` type is lost. I tried moving the `Result` type to the `DeepFunctor[X, A, R[_]]` but that messed up implicit resolution. Theoretically this is a stack overflow question on it's own. I however have no time left to create a simple reproducable example that shows this problem.